# Running React-Native Android App on Ubuntu using Genymotion

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, react-native, genymotion

## Update

Apparently after running `react-native run-android` command the red screen with errors will appear then `react-native start` command should be executed. After that by pressing reload button on red screen the app starts successfully. But I still don't have any clue to start in a single pass without getting any error on `Ubuntu`.

## Original Question

I am trying to run my React-Native Android application on Ubuntu 14.04 using Genymotion simulator. I have followed the guide on [React-Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started-linux.html#content) for Linux users. I keep getting `Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge` error and when I try reloading the error turns into `Could not connect to development server`

I believe to run android app in `MAC` environment using `react-native run-android` command is enough. But on `Linux` this doesn't work or I am missing some point. Could anyone point me what is the proper way of running android react native app on linux environment using GenyMotion as a simulator. I have added a script to my `package.json`. The command is as follows:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start & node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android
```

Strange thing is that this works from time to time but sometimes it just doesn't work. I know that `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` is only required for running on real devices but without it I couldn't manage to run my app on `Ubuntu`.

If I try to run my application using `react-native start` and `react-native run-android` commands I got red screen in the end. I am pasting the outputs hoping it would ring a bell in some experienced user.

```
$ react-native start

 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │ 
 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │ 
 │  prefer.                                                                   │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
Looking for JS files in
   /home/mehmet/WebstormProjects/Sikayetvar 

[10:40:29 AM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[10:40:29 AM] <START> Crawling File System
[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

[10:40:30 AM] <END>   Crawling File System (392ms)
[10:40:30 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[10:40:30 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (143ms)
[10:40:30 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[10:40:30 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (94ms)
[10:40:30 AM] <START> Building Haste Map
[10:40:30 AM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[10:40:30 AM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (56ms)
[10:40:30 AM] <END>   Building Haste Map (147ms)
[10:40:30 AM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (781ms)
```

After the packager is ready I ran the following command:

```
react-native run-android


JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:compileLint
:react-native-camera:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:checkReleaseManifest
:react-native-camera:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee081Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore081Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco081Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline081Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp081Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0191Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareReleaseDependencies
:react-native-camera:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:compileLint
:react-native-hockeyapp:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:checkReleaseManifest
:react-native-hockeyapp:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee061Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore061Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco061Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline061Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp061Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0140Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareNetHockeyappAndroidHockeySDK370Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:prepareReleaseDependencies
:react-native-hockeyapp:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-hockeyapp:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp081Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0230Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareNetHockeyappAndroidHockeySDK370Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareSikayetvarReactNativeCameraUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareSikayetvarReactNativeHockeyappUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'PREVIEW - Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920 - 6.0'
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.342 secs
Starting the app on 192.168.56.101:5555 (/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.56.101:5555 shell am start -n com.myApp/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.myApp/.MainActivity }
```

Then I got the errors on the simulator.

[image]